# Rmagick, ffmpeg and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ffmpeg, rmagick

I have this Rmagick class `ImageList` object with a bunch of frames.

```
frames = ImageList.new("frame_1.png", "frame_2.png", "frame_3.png")
```

When I try to write the frames to `.mpg` with `frames.write('test.mpg')` I get this error on Heroku:

```
Magick::ImageMagickError (delegate failed `"ffmpeg" -v -1 -mbd rd -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 -i "%F%%d.jpg" "%u.%m" 2> "%Z"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1065)
```

I have this config in my `.buildpacks`

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg
```

And `heroku run 'ffmpeg -version' -a my-herokuapp` seems also fine:

```
Running ffmpeg -version on ⬢ my-herokuapp... up, run.2944 (Hobby)
ffmpeg version 3.2.2-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-4) 20161202
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-5 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
```

Comment: Where are you writing the file?

Comment: Into the `/tmp` folder.

Comment: Maybe related to https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/891 ? You may need to update your imagemagick policy.